# Why I can't import my own module in Python

Tags: python, import, module

I dont know why I can't import my own module in my app.
There is a quick example how it works.
Now it works as long as I use "from smt import smt"
[When it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92rAS.png)
But when I try use "import smt" it doesnt work, I dont know why.
Now err. message says my function from that module is not defined
[Doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u939.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `import * from smt` you are importing everything from this file with their original names, but when you use `import smt` you have to call them like `smt.foo()`.